# Python GUI Dropdown Menu shifting everytime

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I want to create a GUI. There is a 2 main dropdown menus. First one where the user select the lesson. Second one where the user select a number and the code genereate new dropdown menu/menus corresponding to selection number. The code is working but there is a problem about second dropdown menu. When I select a number, generates new dropdown menus but the dropdown menu where I select a number from shifting to the right. I want to pin it next to the first dropdown menu. Can anyone help me please? Thanks a lot.

(sticky doesn't work)

Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def on_dropdown_change(event):
    selected_value = int(dropdown_var.get())
    create_extra_dropdowns(selected_value)

def create_extra_dropdowns(count):
    for widget in extra_dropdown_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    for k, parameter in enumerate(parameters_list):
        # Create a checkbox for each parameter and associate it with the corresponding IntVar
        parameter_label = tk.Label(extra_dropdown_frame, text=parameter, width=10, anchor="w")
        parameter_label.grid(row=k+2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="w")
    
    for i in range(count):
        dropdown_var = tk.StringVar()
        dropdown = ttk.Combobox(extra_dropdown_frame, textvariable=dropdown_var,width=7, values=["MT1", "MT2", "LAB", "QUIZ", "HW", "PROJE", "FİNAL"])
        dropdown.grid(row=0, column=i+1, padx=1, pady=1,sticky="w")

        # Her bir dropdown için 15 Entry Box eklemek
        for j in range(15):
            entry_var = tk.StringVar()
            entry_box = tk.Entry(extra_dropdown_frame, textvariable=entry_var,width=5)
            entry_box.grid(row=j+2, column=i+1, padx=5, pady=1,)

def main():
    global dropdown_var
    global extra_dropdown_frame
    global parameters_list
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Dropdown ve Entry Örneği")
    root.geometry("1200x650")
    

    parameters1 = ["Signal and Systems", "Calculus1", "Calculus2", "Circuit Analysis", "Digital Systems 1"]
    dersler_parameter1 = tk.StringVar()
    dersler_parameter1.set("Dersler")  # Set the default value
    dersler_box1 = tk.OptionMenu(root, dersler_parameter1, *parameters1)
    dersler_box1.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10, pady=10,sticky="w")
    # Ana dropdown oluşturma
    dropdown_var = tk.StringVar()
    dropdown = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=dropdown_var,width=5, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
    dropdown.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=1,sticky="w")
    dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_dropdown_change)
    
    parameters_list = ["ÖÇ1 :", "ÖÇ2 :", "ÖÇ3 :", "ÖÇ4 :", "ÖÇ5 :", "ÖÇ6 :",
                   "ÖÇ7 :", "ÖÇ8 :", "ÖÇ9 :", "ÖÇ10 :", "ÖÇ11 :",
                   "ÖÇ12 :", "ÖÇ13 :", "ÖÇ14 :", "ÖÇ15 :",]
    
    extra_dropdown_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    extra_dropdown_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried sticky but doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that the frame for the new elements is positioned in column 0 of the root, and it pushes anything in column 1 or further to the right because columns in Tkinter are always aligned.

To fix it you can put the two elements on top (the OptionMenu and the ComboBox) together in their own frame in column 0, then the ComboBox is no longer in column 1 of the root so it will not be pushed to the right when column 0 is enlarged by the new elements.

Relevant code snippet (the rest is unchanged):

```
parameters1 = ["Signal and Systems", "Calculus1", "Calculus2", "Circuit Analysis", "Digital Systems 1"]
dersler_parameter1 = tk.StringVar()
dersler_parameter1.set("Dersler")  # Set the default value
top_frame = tk.Frame(root)
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
dersler_box1 = tk.OptionMenu(top_frame, dersler_parameter1, *parameters1)
dersler_box1.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10, pady=10,sticky="w")
# Ana dropdown oluşturma
dropdown_var = tk.StringVar()
dropdown = ttk.Combobox(top_frame, textvariable=dropdown_var,width=5, values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
dropdown.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=1,sticky="w")
dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_dropdown_change)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Im new at Python. It look like a simple problem but I got it. Thanks again.